# Reading json data in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I uploaded data in a json file as below

```
import json
characters = ['Robin Hood', 'Aladdin', 'Muhammad Ali', 'Santa Claus', 'Che Guevara']
filename = 'username.json'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(characters, f)
```

I was told not to use the read() method to read the file but instead json's load() method.
The thing is when I try the both I end up with the same terminal output.

```
# same file
with open(filename) as f:
    characters = json.load(f)
    print('Using load():', characters)
```

```
# same file
with open(filename) as f:
    characters = f.read()
    print('Using read():', characters)
```

output

```
Using load(): ['Robin Hood', 'Aladdin', 'Muhammad Ali', 'Santa Claus', 'Che Guevara']
Using read(): ["Robin Hood", "Aladdin", "Muhammad Ali", "Santa Claus", "Che Guevara"]
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the actual output? They shouldn't look the same. The JSON one should have double quotes (`"`). And no, they are not the same thing. The former is the "string representation of a list" while the latter is simply a string.

Comment: It's actually the opposite I get. The latter has double quotes not the json one.

Comment: Use `type(characters)`. Then you'll see the difference

Comment: The difference is apparent now. Superb!

Comment: @O'BrienZimeTaga Yes, by "JSON one" I meant directly printing the JSON file, so it's the one with `read()`, not `json.load()`. Also my point was you should always post the actual output; not the output you think you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

`f.read()` returns a string, *always*.

This is fine for printing purposes, but doesn't matter if the file is JSON or not.

`json.load(f)` will return the appropriate Python object type from the file as well as pseudo-validate the file is really JSON via parsing it.